# getElementById from external not working

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I've tried to hide a div after submit a form, but without success.
So, i want to know the flow of creation div when using external js file.
Consider this code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='style.css'></link>
</head>
<body>
  <script src='external.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

external.js:

```
div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute('id', 'banana');
div1.innerHTML="<form id='form1' method='post' onsubmit='changeScreen()'> firstname: <input type='text'  name='firstname' value='' /> <br> surname:<input type='text' name='surname' value='' /> <br> <input type='submit' id='button2' name='submit2' value='login'/></form>";
document.body.appendChild(div1);


function changeScreen(){

    document.getElementById('banana').style.display='none';   
}
```

(I want to practice on creating elements from external js files so this is the reason the html looks like that and i don't want to change it at all.)

The div created successfully. but when i submit, it just reset the values in the 'firstname' and 'username' . If i just put some alerts in `changeScreen()`, it shows them.
tnx in advance for any ideas (I apologize for the poor english also)!

Comment: Try adding `return false` to your `changeScreen()` function and `onsubmit="return changeScreen()"` so it prevents normal form submission

Comment: I would recommend changing `div1.setAttribute('id', 'banana');` to `div1.id = 'banana';`. It seems odd to use an attribute to indirectly set the element's id, when you can just set it directly, unless you're setting in directly in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your form is posting to the same URL, doing same as refresh. To stay on same page after submit add `return false;` to your code.

```
div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute('id', 'banana');
div1.innerHTML="<form id='form1' method='post' onsubmit='return changeScreen();'> firstname: <input type='text'  name='firstname' value='' /> <br> surname:<input type='text' name='surname' value='' /> <br> <input type='submit' id='button2' name='submit2' value='login'/></form>";
document.body.appendChild(div1);
function changeScreen(){

    document.getElementById('banana').style.display='none';   

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @user3729959 just change 'block' to 'none'